# Show a callout in a iOS UIView

Tags: ios

Is there a way to get custom callouts on a regular UIView in iOS? 
 What I am looking for is a solution similar to Quickactions in Android.

Has anyone tried to do this kind of implementation and been successful at it?

Comment: Can you give more details. Do you want callouts that appear in a `MKMapView`

Comment: No.. I have a UIView..and want to show a callout... underneath a UIButton..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is NO, there is no built-in way to get something like this. However, you can build your own custom callout UIView and add it as a subview to the parent view.

Comment: Yep.. I found this.. https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover worked quite well for me..